# Get all lines from a file after pattern (but from the end)

Tags: shell

I'm trying to filter a huge file (logs from java app) with a linux shell (on debian, but not restricted to).

The file contains more than 40 million lines and what I'm looking for is at the end of the file. They all look like:

```
myJAvaApp | 2021-03-24 13:39:31,028 | etc.
myJAvaApp | 2021-03-24 13:39:31,029 | etc.
myJAvaApp | 2021-03-24 13:39:31,030 | etc.
```

By default, grep (or cat | grep) will read the whole file (which will take too much time).

So I was thinking I would first filter a little: use somehting like `sed '/PATTERN/q' FILE` but starting from the end (so it does not read the whole file) or `sed -n '/PATTERN/,$p'` (which work as intended, but takes way too much time). The pattern would be a date like "13:39:31,029", and I would surely only get a few thousand lines (much more manageable). Then I'll just grep what I need (`grep ERROR` etc.)

No question/answer I found seems to have this specificity (starting from the end up until a pattern).

Comment: Just tail the file and grep for the pattern and ERROR?

Comment: @RamanSailopal I haven't found any option on tails that would help me in this case. Tail will either read a specific number of lines from the end, or just print the current lines (with -f). Maybe there's somehting I didn't see, what were you thinking of ?

Comment: see this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/how-can-i-print-lines-from-file-backwards-without-using-tac

Comment: @Fazlin thanks. As written in the comments, most one-liner using "awk, sed, tac, etc" will be slower the bigger the file is (because the actually read the whole file). However, there are a few interesting bash scripts. I'll wait a little before going that way though.

Comment: [coreutils tac](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tac.c#L193) is very efficient if invoked as `tac inputfile` on a seekable file (ie. **not** `tac <input` nor `... | tac`)

Comment: Are the target strings all continuous?  (All in one lump without any non-targets between.)  Are the target strings at the very end of the file, or just near the end?